# Android Widget layout with three buttons and text

Tags: android, layout, widget

I'd like to write a widget of dimension 3x1 that contains three equal buttons without a space in between.  Instead of buttons, any other kind of View would be ok, as long as pushing them is possible.

I'd like to "overlay" text over all the three buttons so the text is not wrapped within one of the buttons.

What I have tried so far is this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/update"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:layout_width="69dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/att_rec_red"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:text="ABCDEFG" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/update2"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/att_rec_green"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:text="ABCDEFG" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/update3"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/att_rec_blue"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:text="ABCDEFG" >
</TextView>
```

What I did not like are the explicit widths of the `TextView`s. I had to fine-tune these numbers so the three `TextView`s fit exactly into the space of the widget. Is there a better way to do this?

Next question:

I'd like to place ONE text into / over these three `TextView`s (spanning all of them), but (of course) the text is specific to a single `TextView`. I could place three different text messages in there, but not one that spans all of them.

Is there a way to "overlay" text and still have the buttons visible and active (they can be pushed)?

As an alternative:  Is it possible to have just ONE `TextView` and distinguish where within the `TextView` a push happened?  I did not find any example for this but as it is possible to detect where within a `View` a push event happened, is it possible to detect that within the context of a widget?  The setting the notification is done per `View`:

```
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.update, pendingIntent);
```

Is there a way to evaluate the position in a `View` too?

Comment: Yes, i googled before but only found tutorials that cover basic issues.  I edited my original posting to give some more information on what i did so far.

Comment: Ok, it seems the layout of the buttons is quite simple using android:layout_weight.  Also, it seems there is no way to overlay a text over several other views and have the views underneath still pushable.